# Build dynamic array in PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

I need to create an array using a object using different format/structure

I have:

```
$t = object()
$t > user = object()
$t > user > 0 (object) name = 'wilson';
$t > user > 0 (object) first = 'carl';
```

I need to get:

```
$t = array(
 name = wilson
 first name = phil
```

Here's what I tried and where I'm stuck

```
foreach($t as $a) { 
      foreach($a as $l) {
          $arr[$l->0->name] = $l->0->first; // line 10
      }
  }
  print_r($arr);
```

Now I get an error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting
>   T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in homework1-a-1.php on
>   line 10

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Looks like a simple syntax error.  Can't see line 10 so no idea.

Comment: i put line 10 in my edit

Comment: object properties must start with an character. However, I don't understand, what you want to achieve, because it seems, that you mixed up objects and arrays a little bit.

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($t);` and paste the output?

Comment: Is it part of the assignment that you need to construct the object as well? If so, check that you've done everything right with constructing it before you go to the second part where you convert it to array.

Comment: To answer just the syntax error (it's somewhere buried in the manual), you need to use `->{'0'}->` in place of just `->0->`. But I also think you might need a different approach, this looks odd.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is `$t`?  The code for `$t` isn't valid at all.  What do you want `$arr` to look like?  Why do you loop twice over `$t`?

Comment: It's definitely the 0 in `$l->0->name` and `$l->0->first`.  Hence, `unexpected T_LNUMBER`.  Is user an object with array properties?  If so, it would be `$l[0]->name` and `$l[0]->first`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question is confusing. This is what I understand:

You have the following:

- `$t`, which is an object.
- `$t->user`, also an object.
- `$t->user[0]->name = 'wilson'`
- `$t->user[0]->first = 'carl'`

You say you need to get:

- `$t->name = 'wilson'`
- `$t->first = 'carl'`

You say 'phil' in the question, but the given object `$t` has no reference to a 'phil' so I don't know if 'phil' appears out of thin air, or what.

Is this a correct view of the problem? If so, you need to clarify this in the question. saying `$t > user > 0 (object) name` makes no sense.

Sorry this is an "answer", I just couldn't fit all of this in a comment. I will delete it if you clarify the question. Hopefully I am not the only person confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = object()
$t > user = object()
$t > user > 0 (object) name = 'wilson';
$t > user > 0 (object) first = 'carl';
```

This is not valid PHP code.  If you want `$t` in the format you show, just do this:

```
$t = array(
 'name' => 'wilson',
 'first name' => 'phil'
);
```

Now `$t` is an array, with keys `'name'` and `'first name'`.

Your foreach loop doesn't make any sense.  `$t` is an array of two strings.  Looping over it will just give the values `'wilson'` and `'phil'`.

EDIT: Assuming `$t` was given to you, then your for loop should look like this:

```
foreach($t as $a) { 
      foreach($a as $l) {
          $arr[$l->{0}->name] = $l->{0}->first;
      }
  }
```

You can't do `$l->0`.  You need to wrap the `0` in `{}`.  `$l->{0}`.

Comment: The point is it's a homework assignment, the object is given, build an array from it.

Comment: @Truth: Sorry, the question was a little confusing.  The "code" for `$t` makes no sense, I have no idea what `$t` looks like.   He then says he wants `$t` in a certain format (which you said was given), then in his loop, he references `$arr`.  So, I'm not sure what he wants.